# Properly unwrapping UV

Tags: modeling, uv

I'm pretty new to blender and as simple as it is, I'm probably the most confused on UV unwrapping of any other part of blender. I am attempting to unwrap a UV map for a wall with a bevel at the bottom of it. I don't think I'm getting how marking a seam works ultimately, but I was wondering if anyone is able to successfully unwrap and show how you were able to do it.

[image]

Comment: u can make 2 uv map from side and other from front view project from view

Answer (score 1):

First of all in object mode select your wall and apply rotation and scale (Ctrl A) so that your object has rotation 0,0,0 and scale 1,1,1: it's a good practice that affects also UV unwrapping.

Then in edit mode select all and remove doubles (there are 4 doubles that confuse the algorithm), then - in wireframe view - select the little face at the bevel zone between the mesh and her mirrored side and delete it.

Then select all the edges you want to act as seams, in order to preserve the visible faces (front and lateral) without seams.

In the pictures my example.

enter image description here
[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm.. it could be a misunderstanding of how marking seams work... I heard it's like adding cuts to a cube in order to be able to open it all on a flat 2D plain so I tried to work with that logic in order to unwrap my UV... is this how it really works? Or are seams used in a different way?

Comment: Yes it is. The idea is to lay down in 2D every surface of your 3D model, minimizing the stretch and without having seams in the visible areas. Tha cube projection is a classic school example obtaining a single UV island fron a solid, but in the practical everyday work it's normal to have multiple islands if the seams are invisible or placed where they don't disturb.

Comment: I tried marking seams exactly the way you did it to try to understand the process but I ended up with a completely different unwrap after removing the face, applying rotation and scale, and marking the seams as in the image: [https://imgur.com/a/yZPCv] , Also I heard that you were able to move around the UV map to create your own shapes to use for the faces, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your mesh (ngons, normals, doubled verts and applying the rotation) i quickly unwrapped it. People should really focus more on learning how to actually model (in a clean way) even the most basic shapes...
[image]